The program expected this account to be already initialized on InitializeCandidate
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(poll_id: u64)]
pub struct InitializeCandidate<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
pub signer: Signer<'info>,
#[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [b"poll".as_ref(), poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
)]
pub poll_account: Account<'info, PollAccount>,

#[account(
    init,
    payer = signer,
    space = 8 + CandidateAccount::INIT_SPACE,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref(), poll_account.poll_option_index.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
)]
pub candidate_account: Account<'info, CandidateAccount>,

pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

}
Please help out with this
Full Code here
https://github.com/Josh0007-sunday/voteDao.git

Anchor expected all accounts to be initialized when executing an instruction.
I'm guessing that maybe poll_account isn't initialized and that's why you might be encountering an error with it's execution.
Perhaps initialize it with the init constraint or init_if_needed if you are unsure about its initialization
